# Understanding this jQuery .shuffle() plugin or function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could anyone please help me understand how this jQuery plug-in works. I don't understand how this .shuffle() method works. Here is also the JSbin link http://jsbin.com/yefofulohu/2/edit

```
jQuery(function($){
    // unordered list
    $('button').click(function(){
        $('ul').shuffle();
    });

});

(function($){

    $.fn.shuffle = function() {
        return this.each(function(){
            var items = $(this).children().clone(true);
            return (items.length) ? $(this).html($.shuffle(items)) : this;
        });
    }

    $.shuffle = function(arr) {
        for(var j, x, i = arr.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = arr[--i], arr[i] = arr[j], arr[j] = x);
        return arr;
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Understanding the `for` loop's syntax will help you understand what's happening:

```
for(INIT (optional); CONDITION (optional); FINAL EXPRESSION (optional))
   STATEMENT (optional)
```

Though `for` loops are typically used with a specific syntax (`var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++`), you can leave out any or all of the expressions (as the author of this function did) and also do more than a single operation within each expression. Here is a more verbose version of the `$.shuffle` function that is commented:

```
$.shuffle = function(arr) {
    for(var i = arr.length; i > 0; i--) {
      // get random index
      var j = parseInt(Math.random() * i);
      // x = next element
      var x = arr[ i - 1 ];
      // next element = random element
      arr[ i - 1 ] = arr[j];
      // random element = next element's previous value
      arr[j] = x;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Instead of this long-form method, they opted to setup all the variables in the INIT expression, just check `i` in the CONDITION expression (since they are decrementing, the loop will stop at 0), and perform the decrement and assignments in the FINAL EXPRESSION.